# How to remove Visio connector handles?

Tags: vba, microsoft-visio

I'm sure many people share this frustration but I can't find a prior solution.

When I add a standard curved connector to my Visio diagram, I prefer it not to have any of the intermediate handles.  Not sure if "handle" is the correct terminology, I'm talking about the red dots in the middle of the connector that allow you to control the position of the line.

Is there a way to set a default for connectors to not have any handles when first added?

If not, is it possible to write a macro that removes the handles from the selected connector?

[image: Visio Handles]

Comment: "Handle" is correct. Which version of Visio?

Comment: Hi @Paul. The version is 2002 as part of 365.  I'm hoping that's not an indicator of the year of the build as it is with other products.  I'll attach a screenshot.

Comment: I deleted the link to the image with you license details. Not a good idea to have shown that!

Comment: The red dots are new in the online versions I think. Previously they were blue dots.

Comment: Why is it frustrating for you? The handles are useful and only visible when the shape is selected.

Comment: I find that the two handles that are linked to the ends of the line are ideal for shaping the line the way I want.  It is rare that I might want an intermediate handles for finer control.  They tend to be more annoying than useful.